# Simple Conditional Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have this react App component

```
    <BreadCrumb>
            <Chip/>
            <Chip/>
            <Chip/>
                ...
     <BreadCrumb/>

    <CardContainer>
            <Card/>  
            <Card/>
            <Card/>
                ...
    <CardContainer/>

    <Button/>

    <Stores/>
```

I need to set as initial page only the  component, it takes stores from a JSON and map them in a selection

```
class Stores extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          stores: [],
        };
    }

componentDidMount(){
    axios
      .get(URLS.STORES)
      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(stores => {
        this.setState({
          stores
        });
        console.log(this.state.stores)
      });
    }

    render(){
        const options = this.state.stores.map(store => (
            <option key={store.storeCode} value={store.storeCode}>
              {store.storeName}
            </option>
          ));

        return(
            <div>
                   <select>{options}</select>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

i need to render only this component as initial page and after selecting a store to render the entire App, without the stores component, how can i use React router to achieve this?

Comment: can you share you code with codesandbox

Comment: what code would you like to see? the whole app?

Comment: yeap if possible

Comment: sorry i can't share the whole app right now in code sandbox because of the number of components and it wouldm't work anyway without the JSON, and i can't share the json